# Tomcat Logging Multiple Days Behind

Tags: logging, tomcat

I have been noticing on our largish production deployment of Tomcat that some logs display this issue of being "multiple days behind" in the logging output.  We have a 3rd-party vendor application installed on an 8-core server which runs a total of 9 applications in Tomcat, with a typical load of 20-30 concurrent users.

For example, when reviewing a SOAP API log request, I see activity being logged that looks like this:

```
[2013-11-25 01:16:01,102] Pay History 11/27/2013 has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:01,321] PRItemPayHist SALARY has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:01,759] Checkbook Item 11/27/2013 has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:01,868] PRItemEmployeeTaxHist Federal Income Tax has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:01,977] PRItemEmployeeTaxHist FICA Medicare has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:02,087] PRItemEmployeeTaxHist FICA Social Security has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:02,196] PRItemEmployeeTaxHist Maine State Income Tax has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:02,524] PRItemEmployerTaxHist FICA Medicare has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:02,634] PRItemEmployerTaxHist FICA Social Security has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:02,743] PRItemEmployerTaxHist WORKERS COMP has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:02,962] Checkbook Direct Deposit Item Co Checkbook Direct Deposit Item Co has been updated by Web API user Application User at 11/21/2013 06:27 PM
[2013-11-25 01:16:03,071] updateArr updated: 11 time=5391 ms
[2013-11-25 08:41:00,930] Unloaded from WEBAPI Server at 11/21/2013 10:16 PM
```

Notice how the time of logging is 2013-11-25, but the detail being logged says 11/21/2013.  I am very unfamiliar with Tomcat and the logging mechanism, but this seems very unusual?  Can the logging get backed up in queue that far?  Or actual web requests get queued for 4 days before they are actually handled?